# I just decrypted a file with openssl, what file format has these encodings inside of it?

Tags: encryption, openssl

Inside of the file has a bunch of these types of encodings.
I have no idea how this file was encrypted so trying to figure out what program this may be from.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf830
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;\f1\froman\fcharset0 Times-Roman;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (RTF).